# I need a program that will ask the user to enter the information to save, line to line in a file. How can I do it?

Tags: java

I need a program that will ask the user to enter the information to save, line to line in a file. How can I do it?

It has to look like this:

```
Please, choose an option:

1. Read a file

2. Write in a new file

2

File name? problema.txt

How many lines do you want to write? 2


Write line 1: Hey

Write line 2: How are you?

Done! The file problema.txt has been created and updated with the content given.
```

I have tried in various ways but I have not succeeded. First I have done it in a two-dimensional array but I can not jump to the next line.

Then I tried it with the ".newline" method without the array but it does not let me save more than one word.

Attempt 1

```
System.out.println("How many lines do you want to write? ");
int mida = sc.nextInt();


PrintStream escriptor = new PrintStream(f);
String [][] dades = new String [mida][3];

for (int i = 0; i < dades.length; i++) {

  System.out.println("Write line " + i + " :");
  for (int y=0; y < dades[i].length; y++) {

    String paraula = sc.next();
    System.out.println(paraula + " " + y);

    dades[i][y] = paraula;

    escriptor.print(" " + dades[i][y]);


  }
  escriptor.println();
}
```

Attempt 2

```
System.out.println("How many lines do you want to write? ");
int mida = sc.nextInt();

PrintStream escriptor = new PrintStream(f);
BufferedWriter ficheroSalida = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(file1)));

for (int i = 0; i < mida; i++) {

  System.out.println("Write line " + i + " :");
  String paraula = sc.next();
  ficheroSalida.write (paraula);
  ficheroSalida.newLine();
  ficheroSalida.flush();

}

System.out.println("Done! The file " + fitxer + " has been created and updated with the content given. ");

escriptor.close();
```

Attempt 1:

```
Write line 1: Hey How are

Write line 1: you...
```

Attempt 2:

```
Write line 1: Hey

Write line 2: How

Write line 3: are

Write line 4: you

Write line 5: ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're almost there. First, I'd use a `java.io.FileWriter` in order to write the strings to a file.

It's not really necessary to use an array here if you just want to write the lines to a file.

You should also use the `try`-with-resources statement in order to create your writer. This makes sure that `escriptor.close()` gets called even if there is an error. You don't need to call `.flush()` in this case either because this will be done before the handles gets closed. It was good that you intended to do this on your own but in general its safer to use this special kind of statement whenever possible.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        File f = new File("/tmp/output.txt");

        System.out.println("How many lines do you want to write? ");
        int mida = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine(); // Consume next empty line

        try (FileWriter escriptor = new FileWriter(f)) {

            for (int i = 0; i < mida; i++) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Write line %d:", i + 1));
                String paraula = sc.nextLine();
                escriptor.write(String.format("%s\n", paraula));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases where your text file is kind of small and usage of streamreaders/streamwriters is not required, you can read the text, add what you want and write it all over again. Check this example:

```
public class ReadWrite {
    private static Scanner scanner;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
        System.out.println("Yo, which file would you like to edit from " + desktop.getAbsolutePath() + "?");
        String fileName = scanner.next();
        File textFile = new File(desktop, fileName);
        if (!textFile.exists()) {
            System.err.println("File " + textFile.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String fileContent = readFileContent(textFile);

        System.out.println("How many lines would you like to add?");

        int lineNumber = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= lineNumber; i++) {
            System.out.println("Write line number #" + i + ":");
            String line = scanner.next();
            fileContent += line;
            fileContent += System.lineSeparator();
        }

        //Write all the content again
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(textFile)) {
            out.write(fileContent);
            out.flush();
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    private static String readFileContent(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            String everything = sb.toString();
            return everything;
        }
    }
}
```

An execution of the example would be:

```
Yo, which file would you like to edit from C:\Users\George\Desktop?
hello.txt
How many lines would you like to add?
4
Write line number #1:
Hello
Write line number #2:
Stack
Write line number #3:
Over
Write line number #4:
Flow
```

with the file containing after:

```
Hello
Stack
Over
Flow
```

And if you run again, with the following input:

```
Yo, which file would you like to edit from C:\Users\George\Desktop?
hello.txt
How many lines would you like to add?
2
Write line number #1:
Hey
Write line number #2:
too
```

text file will contain:

```
Hello
Stack
Over
Flow
Hey
too
```

**However**, if you try to do it with huge files, your memory will not be enough, hence an `OutOfMemoryError` will be thrown. But for small files, it is ok.